# Stored procedure to find time difference between all the apps in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns:

```
[app_guid]
[app_name]
[created_at]
[state]
[previous_state]
[totaltime]
```

This is some sample data

```
guid                                    app_guid                                app_name    created_at                  state           previous_state  totaltime
F7CB3B18-EFAC-40A0-8A04-01AD207547B8    ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59    test-app123    2019-11-19 20:41:59.000      STARTED         STOPPED 
C383A3BA-3FA7-4988-B61C-01D5BB850CB0    ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59    test-app123    2019-11-20 04:01:51.000      STOPPED         STARTED 
D782B84B-28FE-4F10-A053-0237EE0A369A    ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59    test-app123    2019-11-19 20:43:12.000      BUILDPACK_SET   STARTED
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a stored procedure that will find the time difference where

`state = STARTED & previous_state = STOPPED` and `state = STOPPED & previous_state = STARTED` and insert it into the `totaltime` column.

Sample output:

```
guid                                    app_guid                                app_name    created_at                      state           previous_state  totaltime
F7CB3B18-EFAC-40A0-8A04-01AD207547B8    ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59    test-app123    2019-11-19 20:41:59.000      STARTED         STOPPED      DONE
C383A3BA-3FA7-4988-B61C-01D5BB850CB0    ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59    test-app123    2019-11-20 04:01:51.000      STOPPED         STARTED      26392 (value in seconds)
D782B84B-28FE-4F10-A053-0237EE0A369A    ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59    test-app123    2019-11-19 20:43:12.000      BUILDPACK_SET   STARTED      DONE
```

Populate `totaltime` column with the time difference and `DONE`.

What I have tried so far:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        created_at, state, previous_state, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY STATE) as RN
    FROM
        Table 
    WHERE
        state IN ('STARTED', 'STOPPED')
    ORDER BY 
        created_at ASC
)
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, sta.created_at, en.created_at) 
FROM
    CTE sta
INNER JOIN
    CTE en ON sta.RN = en.RN
```

How do I do this any hints direction will be useful.

Comment: Take a look at [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The real challenge though is figuring out what you can use for ordering.

Comment: Your update still does not have unique values in your table. You added a guid in the desired output but that is not the same thing as in the base table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with you sample data. Not really sure what you want here but this does return the value you wanted on the row with "STOPPED".

In your question you stated you want to update the existing row with the calculated value. However, you don't have anything in your sample that you can use as a row identifier. There is nothing unique in your data from the looks of things.

```
declare @Something table
(
    app_guid varchar(50) --can't use uniqueidentifier because your sample data is not a valid guid.
    , app_name varchar(20)
    , created_at datetime
    , state varchar(20)
    , previous_state varchar(20)
)

insert @Something values
('ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59', 'test-app123', '2019-11-19 20:41:59.000', 'STARTED', 'STOPPED')
, ('ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59', 'test-app123', '2019-11-20 04:01:51.000', 'STOPPED', 'STARTED')
, ('ASC4222C-77C8-408C-8B3B-AB4757197B59', 'test-app123', '2019-11-19 20:43:12.000', 'BUILDPACK_SET', 'STARTED')

select *
    , LAG(created_at, 1)over(partition by app_guid order by created_at)
    , datediff(second, LAG(created_at, 1)over(partition by app_guid order by created_at), created_at)
from @Something s
where s.state in ('STARTED','STOPPED')
```

---EDIT to include UPDATE---

Your sample data is still a little odd but that is likely just because this is a simplified version. Here is how you could do this to update the base table.

```
declare @Something table
(
    app_guid uniqueidentifier
    , app_name varchar(20)
    , created_at datetime
    , state varchar(20)
    , previous_state varchar(20)
    , totaltime int
)

insert @Something values
(newid(), 'test-app123', '2019-11-19 20:41:59.000', 'STARTED', 'STOPPED', null)
, (newid(), 'test-app123', '2019-11-20 04:01:51.000', 'STOPPED', 'STARTED', null)
, (newid(), 'test-app123', '2019-11-19 20:43:12.000', 'BUILDPACK_SET', 'STARTED', null)
;

with MyCTE as
(
    select *
        , CalcTime = datediff(second, LAG(created_at, 1)over(partition by app_name order by created_at), created_at)
    from @Something s
    where s.state in ('STARTED','STOPPED')
)

update MyCTE
set totaltime = CalcTime

select *
from @Something
```

Comment: actually there a column name `guid` which is a primary key

Comment: It can't be the primary key, you have three rows with the same value.

Comment: Not in your sample data it doesn't. But if the real data that is true then no biggie to update your table

Comment: @Sam see my updated answer which now has a way you can update your base table.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `lag()` and conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when (state = 'STARTED' and previous_state = 'STOPPED') or
                  (state = 'STOPPED' and previous_state = 'STARTED')
             then datediff(second,
                           lag(created_at) over (partition by app_guid order by created_at)
                           created_at
        end) as total_time                  
from t;
```

I would not recommend trying to store both strings and numbers in the same column, so this has `NULL` for rows that don't match the conditions.